# How can I cancel the code in touchesEnded when touchesBegan begins again

Tags: ios, xcode, touchesbegan

I dont know if this is possible... I have this code in touchesEnded:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(GameOver) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
```

However, if you touch the screen again before the 3 seconds is up, I want to cancel the calling  of GameOver.  Any idea how I can do this.

In touchesBegan, I tried something like this:

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self
                                         selector:@selector(touchesEnded:withEvent:)
                                           object:nil];
```

This did not work.

Comment: Isn't this the same question you asked before? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27585523/how-to-call-gameover-after-3-second-unless-touchesbegan-again

Comment: yea haha I just wanted to reword it because I decided I want to take a separate approach...I deleted that one though.

Answer (score 0):

Your `selector` value is wrong in your `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget` call, that's all. If the original selector in `performSelector` was `GameOver` then obviously the perform request you are canceling must be specified as `GameOver`.

This is perfectly clear from the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object:

Comment: And please, don't name a method `GameOver` with a capital letter like that, ever again, okay? It just annoys the frog.

Comment: Thank you so much.  That fixed it!  Sorry about my coding, I'm a little new to this.